# Using Pandas .diff() on a time series column with a groupby

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `CSV` file of customer purchases in no particular order that I read into a `Pandas` `Dataframe`. I'd like to add a column for each purchase and show how much time has passed since the last purchase, grouped by customer. I'm not sure where it's getting the differences, but they are much too large (even if in seconds).

CSV:

```
Customer Id,Purchase Date
4543,1/1/2015
4543,2/5/2015
4543,3/15/2015
2322,1/1/2015
2322,3/1/2015
2322,2/1/2015
```

Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
start = time.time()
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', low_memory=False)
data = data.sort_values(by=['Customer Id', 'Purchase Date'])
data['Purchase Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Purchase Date'])
data['Purchase Difference'] = (data.groupby(['Customer Id'])['Purchase Date']
                         .diff()
                         .fillna('-')
                       )
print data
```

Output:

```
    Customer Id Purchase Date Purchase Difference
3         2322    2015-01-01                   -
5         2322    2015-02-01    2678400000000000
4         2322    2015-03-01    2419200000000000
0         4543    2015-01-01                   -
1         4543    2015-02-05    3024000000000000
2         4543    2015-03-15    328320000000000
```

Desired Output:

```
   Customer Id Purchase Date  Purchase Difference
3         2322    2015-01-01                  -
5         2322    2015-02-01              31 days
4         2322    2015-03-01              28 days
0         4543    2015-01-01                  -
1         4543    2015-02-05              35 days
2         4543    2015-03-15              38 days
```

Comment: Is the last dataframe really your desired output, or are the differences too large there?

Comment: @IanS Thanks. I did not mean that. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just apply `diff` to the `Purchase Date` column once it has been converted to a Timestamp.

```
df['Purchase Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Purchase Date'])
df.sort_values(['Customer Id', 'Purchase Date'], inplace=True)    
df['Purchase Difference'] = \
    [str(n.days) + ' day' + 's' if n > pd.Timedelta(days=1) else '' if pd.notnull(n) else "" 
     for n in df.groupby('Customer Id', sort=False)['Purchase Date'].diff()]

>>> df
   Customer Id Purchase Date Purchase Difference
3         2322    2015-01-01                    
5         2322    2015-02-01             31 days
4         2322    2015-03-01             28 days
0         4543    2015-01-01                    
1         4543    2015-02-05             35 days
2         4543    2015-03-15             38 days
6         4543    2015-03-15
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can add to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter `parse_dates` for parsing `datetime`, [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Customer Id,Purchase Date
4543,1/1/2015
4543,2/5/2015
4543,3/15/2015
2322,1/1/2015
2322,3/1/2015
2322,2/1/2015"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['Purchase Date'])

data.sort_values(by=['Customer Id', 'Purchase Date'], inplace=True)

data['Purchase Difference'] = data.groupby(['Customer Id'])['Purchase Date'].diff()
print data
   Customer Id Purchase Date  Purchase Difference
3         2322    2015-01-01                  NaT
5         2322    2015-02-01              31 days
4         2322    2015-03-01              28 days
0         4543    2015-01-01                  NaT
1         4543    2015-02-05              35 days
2         4543    2015-03-15              38 days
```

Comment: I like your second approach, which is basically what I did, but adding the fillna() function seems to be what results in the huge numbers.

Comment: Thanks. What solution is betterby performance? Alexander's or my? Is better parse datetime in read_csv or by to_datetime? Thanks.

Comment: Ran each on 60,000 rows of a csv file. @Alexander was done in 7.75 seconds. Yours was done in 9.39 seconds.

Comment: if i then want to calculate the mean?

Comment: @fabio.geraci - Do you think change `['Purchase Date'].diff()` to `['Purchase Date'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.mean())` ?